# Laravel5.4 Error, SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'users' already exists

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5

**Specifications:**

Laravel Version: 5.4
PHP Version: 7.0.9
Composer version 1.9.0
XAMP

**Description:**

*In Connection.php line 647:*

SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'users' already exists (SQL: create table `users` (
  `id` int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key, `name` varchar(255) not null, `email` varchar(255) not null,
  `password` varchar(255) not null, `remember_token` varchar(100) null, `created_at` timestamp null, `updated_at` tim
  estamp null) default character set utf8mb4 collate utf8mb4_unicode_ci)

*In Connection.php line 449:*

SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'users' already exists

**Problem:**
I have created models and tables of user and Product. It successfully created both migrations and tables but failed to migrate on phpmyadmin sql.

**Steps I tried:**
I have dropped all database and recreated it but still it gives error.
I have also used tinker but error is same.

**code:**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('users');
    }
}
```

Comment: do you have two migrations where you have `Schema::create('users',...`?

Comment: I have two migrations, Users and Products. In user i have Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) and In Products i have Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table)

Comment: what packages are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `users` table migration file add this line in `up()` method

```
    Schema::dropIfExists('users');
```

Like this

```
    public function up()
    {
     Schema::dropIfExists('users');
     Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
     });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

> Try to add the following condition before **Schema::create()**

```
if (!Schema::hasTable('users')) {
        Schema::create('users',...)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your migration table if the "User" Table is recorded there, delete it and then do a single migration using this artisan command

```
php artisan migrate:refresh --path=/database/migrations/fileName.php
```

Or Do reset the migration using the following and then migrate again

```
php artisan migrate:reset
```