# SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'tags' already exists

Tags: laravel

[image]

[image]

When ran `php artisan migrate` it will show out error.

I try drop all file and install again, it show out this why?

> 2023_03_09_044748_create_tag_tables ................................. 6ms FAIL
>
> Illuminate\Database\QueryException

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel5.4 Error, SQLSTATE\[42S01\]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'users' already exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58909540/laravel5-4-error-sqlstate42s01-base-table-or-view-already-exists-1050-table)

Comment: Try also running ````php artisan migrate:fresh````

Comment: You already have a migration named `..._create_tags_table.php`, what does it do?

Comment: there is a migration in your migration path who wants to recreate the tag table that already exist in your database. 
you can simply delete it.

Comment: the tag table only exist 1 in database, i try to delete it but still doesn't works.

Comment: What is the table name inside 2023_03_09_044748_create_tag_tables?

Comment: public function up(): void
    {
        Schema::create('tags', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();

            $table->json('name');
            $table->json('slug');
            $table->string('type')->nullable();
            $table->integer('order_column')->nullable();

            $table->timestamps();
        });    @jeremykenedy

Comment: @SeewpengNea Don't post code in the comments, instead [edit] your question and append additional information there. Thanks

Comment: @SeewpengNea I don't understand what you don't understand... You are trying to create (again) a table named `tags`... So, go to each migration (in order) and see which one is oroginally creating the table, and then find the one that is trying to create it again... This should not even be a question.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in `2023_03_09_044748_create_tag_tables`, Change the table name to `tag`

Run
`composer dump-autoload` and then `php artisan migrate:fresh`

Answer (score 1):

you have two tables named "tags" in your migration files
_create_tags_table and _create_tag_table
check the create method in both migrations and rename or delete one.

[image]

Comment: I try to delete one of them and ran "php artisan migrate" still the same error

Comment: if you don't have data in your application try to run 
`php artisan migrate:fresh` 
after deleting the migration file

Comment: After run php artisan migrate:fresh [2023_03_09_134729_create_tag_tables] it show failed and come out same error.

Answer (score 1):

You should make sure to name tables the "Laravel way" and follow their naming conventions.

In this case, you named the migration `..._create_tag_tables`, but the table you create is called `tags`. Make sure to name the migration the same way.

You already have a migration that creates the `tags` table. If you want to change that one, you have two options:

If not deployed yet, you can update the existing migration to your needs. Then run `php artisan migrate:fresh`, what will empty the database and set it up again (all data will get lost).

**But never change deployed (or better even pushed) migrations as they will not be run again.**

In that case, create a new migration that [updates](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/migrations#updating-tables) the already existing table.